# Firemonkey App failed to upload to Mac App Store

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, delphi, firemonkey

I am using Delphi RAD Studio XE3 to build my mac app, when I try to upload the PKG file by using Application Loader, it shows the following error message:

Application Loader fail message : 
The application is invalid. The executable ((null)) is missing a required architecture. At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present i386, x86_64

What's wrong? How to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you set it to OSX in the project manager? Also take a look at this thread: http://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?messageID=601266

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue is actually due to wrong executable filename and wrong code signing, this page helped me to solve it: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/126390-Can-t-submit-app-to-the-Mac-app-store